# Reference an export in React

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, when I import a css file, React creates a special Javascript file in place of the css file:

```
import myCss from '../../res/css/app.css';
```

And here is the file structure of the app and the app.css file that gets created:

[image: Exported module in React]

In the right pane in DevTools, it is clear to me that the values of the css have been loaded. I would like to access these but have no idea how. They are clearly stored in an array called exports, which is stored in a variable called module. But I have no idea how to reference that array item since I would have to know what module.id is.

Answer (score 1):

don't import CSS like a js module;

```
import '../../res/css/app.css';
```

this syntax will make CSS classes available to use in current file;

Comment: Unfortunately if I do it that way, I don't have access to the entire set of css items in a JSON object, which is what I really need. I need to process the css data before they get applied.